# Connect Facebook comment plugin with moderation app

Tags: facebook, plugins, shopify, comments

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook comments plugin in a Shopify theme. I need to activate moderation, so that a moderator has to accept comments, before they're actually published on the site.

I have added `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXX" />` to the `<head>` of my theme, I added  `<div id="fb-root"></div><script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v10.0&appId=XXXXX" nonce="UznvJecH"></script>` to the `<body>`, and I added `<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{ shop.url }}/blogs/{{ article.handle }}" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-lazy="true" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>` where I want the comment widget to show up.

(Each instance of `XXXXX` is of course replaced with the app ID of an app I created in my Facebook Developers account. The app was set to live status, and it has my account set as a moderator under "roles".)

The widget is showing up fine, and you can post comments. But the comments are published to the site right away, and they never show up in my Comment Moderation tool view.

Seems like the plugin isn't connected properly to the moderation app, but I can't figure out why. Does anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you send the site URL through the Facebook debug tool, to refresh their meta data cache?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried running the URL through the debug tool, and I noticed that canonical URL said "/password". This is because my store is in dev mode, and Shopify hides it behind a password page. This is probably why FB isn't able to connect the app then.

Answer (score 0):

For future interest: Like mentioned in the comment above, the problem turned out to be Shopify's password page, that prevents Facebook from properly connecting the app.

I tested it on a live theme without a password page, and it works as intended.